# Ruby rake tasks thread optimization

Tags: ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing, rake

I have some rake tasks that need to run every hour approximately, each one of them has to contact a web site, download a file and import the file into my db.

I was wondering what the best approach would be in terms of efficiency and speed of execution.
Am I correct if I think that making a thread for each task will save me some time? By doing so I should be able to minimize the time spent waiting for the server response to that of the slowest one among the threads.

Once downloaded the files, I was thinking of using `gem "parallel"` for importing data into the db from large csv and xml files.

Please let me know should you have any suggestions.

Comment: How many files are there? Do you download all of the files in one task or have many tasks?

Comment: At the moment I have 3 tasks, and 3 files to download from 3 different web locations: Each task has its file to download and import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When number of such files is low, you do not care for order of execution and can afford some extra memory - simpliest solution is just to run them in different processes by cron (for example - `gem 'whenever'`).

If there're more - use some http gems for parallel downloading - `typhoeus`, `curb`, `em-http-request` etc

Comment: Is it ok even when files are quite big and take a lot of time to be processed? With big I mean some 20k rows csv files that need to be parsed and mapped to model.

Comment: @Jack if you opt for separate process - then no problems, only have to care about imports being able to run in parallel

Comment: I'll try this approach then, thank you for your time!